# updating redux state in reducer having error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I can't understand after hours of googling and reading SOF that why react does not let me update the redux state simply pushing new objects to the array. My action makes:

```
 dispatch({ type: ENG_ARR_UPDATE, payload:  {w,q,a,i}});
```

in reducer, simply:

```
return { ...state, addedwords: [...state.addedwords, {w:action.payload.w}]};
```

and I get the error "in reducer" (not in component and rendering)

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {w})
```

now if I alter the code to:

```
return { ...state, addedwords: [...state.addedwords, JSON.stringify(action.payload)]};
```

I no more get the error, but then I can not work with my object as it is a string!

Please, what I don't understand here?

**Edit**

the demo usage of the state is:

```
<p>Update received: {this.props.waddedok}</p>
```

**the component code:**

```
class EngCRUD extends React.Component {
  submit = (wordobj) => {
      if(wordobj.word && wordobj.quote && wordobj.author){
        this.props.saveEngWord(wordobj);
        this.props.doreset('eng_w_crud_form');
      }
   }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <p>TCRUD page for EN-W</p>
        <p>Update received: {this.props.waddedok}</p>
        <WordCrudForm onSubmit={this.submit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { waddedok: state.engWord.addedwords };//English word state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(EngCRUD);
```

**Edit 2 - maybe the problem is in how I made my initial state?**

```
import {
ENG_ARR_UPDATE
} from '../actions/types';

  export default function(state = {addedwords:[]}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ENG_ARR_UPDATE:
        return { ...state, addedwords: [...state.addedwords, {w:'dummy'}]};
    }

    return state;
  }
```

Comment: Can we see how you use that part of state in your component?

Comment: Yes please, I edited and added the code.

Comment: Also added the reducer file, as I really can't suspect to anything in the simple demo-component, maybe my reducer has problem, I suspect there's something that I don't understand about defining the initial state. Please see.

Comment: I understand the problem. Since you have an array in state (`state.engWord.addedwords`) React is attempting to render all the elements of the array, which if they're all strings would be just text nodes. But since you're adding an object inside the array, React spits out the error. Map over the array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is from [Andrew Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647260/andrew-li) I just write in detail so maybe useful for someone else. I edited my component and this is the working demo code I came to:

```
//my_action.js:
dispatch({ type: ENG_ARR_UPDATE, payload:  {w,q,a,i}});

//my_reducer.js:
return { ...state, addedwords: [...state.addedwords, action.payload]};

//component code:
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <NewllyAddedWordList warr={this.props.waddedok}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { waddedok: state.engWord.addedwords};
}

//NewllyAddedWordList.js
const NewllyAddedWordList = ({warr}) => (
    <div>{warr.map(map2c)}</div>
   );

function map2c(item, i) {
    let m = item.w + ", "+item.q;
    return m;
}

export default NewllyAddedWordList;
```